# Loss functions for regression proof

Tags: regression, least-squares, loss-functions, conditional-expectation

I'm using Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning. In section 1.5.5, loss functions for regression, namely the squared loss, is discussed.

$\mathbb{E}[L] = \displaystyle\int\int \{ y(x)-t\}^{2}p(x,t) dx dt $

The book makes the following remark:

$\{ y(x)-t\}^{2} = \{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x] + \mathbb{E}[t|x] - t \}^{2}  
\\ = \{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x] \}^{2} + 2\{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x]\}\{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\} + \{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\}^{2}$

The resulting expression shown above is substituted into the loss function, integrated over $t$, and then it is seen that the cross-term (the second term) vanishes. The result obtained is:

$\mathbb{E}[L] = \displaystyle\int\int \{ y(x)-t\}^{2}p(x,t) dx dt \\ = \displaystyle\int \{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x] \}^{2} p(x) dx + \displaystyle\int \{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\}^{2} p(x) dx$

What I don't understand is the algebra involved to get the final result. Why does the cross-term vanish? For the last term, how are you bringing $t$ outside the integral over $t$? Perhaps I am missing something here, could someone care to explain?

Comment: I don't have the book, but is this perhaps Eq. (1.90) on p. 47?https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf

Comment: That is, the errata above corrects "the integrand of the second integral" to $var[t\mid x]$, which would make sense here but I cannot verify that the erratum is referring to the same equation as this question.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to explain the way I understood it, explaining each and every step on the way.

**Assumptions:**

1. $g(x,t)$ is a function of x and t.
2. $p(x,t)$ is a joint distribution over $x$ and $t$.

**Basic formulas:**

$$\mathbb{E}_t[g|x] = \int_t{g(x,t)p(t|x)\mathop{dt}} \ (\mathbb{E}_t[g|x] \text{ is a function of $x$ and constant w.r.t. } t) \tag{1}\label{1} $$
$$\mathbb{E}_t[t|x] = \int_t{t.p(t|x)\mathop{dt}} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
$\operatorname{var}_t[t|x] = \int_t{(t - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^2p(t|x)\mathop{dt}} = \mathbb{E}_t[(t - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^2 | x] \tag{3}\label{3}$
$$
\eqalign{\mathbb{E}_t[f(x)g(x,t)|x] 
&= \int_t{f(x)g(x,t)p(t|x)\mathop{dt}} \\
&= f(x)\int_t{g(x,t)p(t|x)\mathop{dt}} \\
&= f(x) \ \mathbb{E}_t[g|x] }
\tag{4}\label{4}$$
$$\mathbb{E}_t[f(x)|x] = f(x) \tag{4a}\label{4a}$$
$$\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[g] = \mathbb{E}_x[\mathbb{E}_t[g|x]] \tag{5}\label{5}$$

We derive the last formula above.
$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[g]
&= \int_x\int_tg(x,t)p(x,t)\mathop{dx}\mathop{dt}\\
&= \int_x\int_tg(x,t)p(x)p(t|x)\mathop{dx}\mathop{dt}\\
&= \int_x p(x)\int_t g(x,t)p(t|x)\mathop{dt}\mathop{dx}\\
&= \int_x \mathbb{E}_t[g|x]p(x)\mathop{dx}  \text{  (using \ref{1}) }  \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x [\mathbb{E}_t[g|x]] \\
}
$$

**Derivation of the expected loss:**

Represent the Loss function in the form as below. Please notice the subscript $t$ in the $\mathbb{E}_t$ notations. This was omitted in the book, but I added it here for clarity.
$$
\eqalign{
L(x,t) &= (y(x)-t)^{2} \\
&= (y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^{2} + 2(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t) + (\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t)^{2} \\
&= L_1 + 2L_2 + L_3
}
$$

Hence the joint expectation can be represented as:
$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L]
&= \mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_1] + 2\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_2] + \mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_3]
}
$$

We derive the 3 expectations:
$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_1] 
&= \mathbb{E}_{x,t}[(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^{2}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[ \ \mathbb{E}_t[(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^{2} | x] \ ] \ \ \text{  (using \ref{5}) } \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x] )^{2}]  \text{  (using \ref{4a}, as the operand is a function of $x$ only)} \\
}
$$

$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_2] 
&= \mathbb{E}_{x,t}[(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[ \ \mathbb{E}_t[\{(y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t)\} \ | \ x] \ ] \text{  (using \ref{5}) } \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[ \ (y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x]) \ \mathbb{E}_t[(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t) | x] \ \ ] \ \text{  (using \ref{4} on the inner expectation)}
}
$$

Considering only the inner expectation:
$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_t[(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t) | x]
&= \mathbb{E}_t[\mathbb{E}_t[t|x] | x] - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x] \text{ (using inearity of $\mathbb{E}$)} \\
&= \mathbb{E}_t[t|x] - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x]  \text{  (using \ref{4a} as $\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]$ is a function of $x$)}\\
&= 0
}
$$

Therefore,
$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_2] 
&= \mathbb{E}_x[ \ (y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x]) \ \cdot \ 0 \ ] \\
&= 0
}
$$

$$
\eqalign{
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L_3] 
&= \mathbb{E}_{x,t}[(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t)^{2}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[ \ \mathbb{E}_t[(\mathbb{E}_t[t|x]-t)^{2} | x] \ ]  \text{  (using \ref{5}) } \\
&= \mathbb{E}_x[\operatorname{var}_t[t|x]] \text{  (using \ref{3}) }
}
$$

Putting them all together and expressing the $\mathbb{E}_x$ terms as integrals under $x$, we get the following form:

$$
\mathbb{E}_{x,t}[L] = \int_x (y(x) - \mathbb{E}_t[t|x])^2 p(x)\mathop{dx} + \int_x \operatorname{var}_t[t|x] p(x) \mathop{dx}
$$

**Note:** As mentioned by @Juho Kokkalla, the erroneous last term in the book is corrected in the errata.

Answer (score 3):

This proof is easier if you iterate expectations. You want to show that $\mathbb{E}(y|x)$ is in a sense the best predictor of $t$, so you want to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}[(y(x) - t)^2] \ge \mathbb{E}[\{\mathbb{E}(t \vert x) - t\}^2]
$$
for any $y(x)$.

It's easier to first consider $\mathbb{E}[(y(x) - t)^2 \vert x]$. If you do this and apply the trick you mentioned above (adding and subtracting a conditional expectation), you can get
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}[(y(x) - t)^2 \vert x] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[\{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x] \}^{2}\vert x] + 2\mathbb{E}[\{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x]\}\{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\}\vert x] + \mathbb{E}[\{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\}^{2}\vert x] \\
&= \{y(x) - \mathbb{E}[t|x] \}^{2} + 0 + \mathbb{E}[\{\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t\}^{2}\vert x] .
\end{align*}
Notice that the cross term here becomes $0$ when you do this because of linearity and the fact that you can pull out any $x-$measurable random variables from the conditional expectation. For more details, see whuber's comment below.

And then you finally get the desired result by taking expectations again (with respect to $p(x)$). No differentiation needed.

Comment: +1 It's nice to see a brief rigorous argument. (But one has to guess what you mean by "$f(x)$" at the end.) Because the crucial part of the analysis isn't the linearity of expectation, but why the cross term disappears, you might want to elaborate on that. Writing $g(x)$ for $y(x)-\mathbb{E}[t|x]$, I believe you are saying that$$\eqalign{\mathbb{E}[g(x)\ (\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t)\mid x]&=g(x)\ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[t|x]-t]\mid x]\\&=g(x)\left(\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[t|x]\mid x]-\mathbb{E}[t\mid x]\right)\\&=g(x)\left(\mathbb{E}[t|x]-\mathbb{E}[t|x]\right)\\&=0.}$$

Comment: @whuber yes that's right. And I'll make the change from $f(x)$ to OP's notation $p(x)$.