# Why is $E_t[g|x]$ the notation of $\int_t g(x,t)p(t|x)dt$?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Why is $E_t[g|x]$ the notation of $\int_t g(x,t)p(t|x)dt$?

This is seen in the equation(1) of the first answer of this question [Loss functions for regression proof](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228561/loss-functions-for-regression-proof)

This notation is also seen in the equation(1.89) of the book PRML.

Is there any statistical books or materials I can refer to? I am especially confused about, why $E_t[g|x]$ is not written as $E_{t|x}[g]$ since it uses the probability $p(t|x)$?

I am really not good at statistics and conditional expectation.

Comment: It's bad notation: the "$t$" is meaningless in $E_t[g\mid x]$ and in $E_{t\mid x}[g].$

Comment: @whuber is there a better notation for $\int_t g(x,t)p(t|x)dt$?

Comment: Sure: because this quantity depends on $g$ and either $p$ (presumably a density) or $x$ (presumably a random variable with density $p$), you may use any notation that refers to $g$ and $p$ (or makes them clear in context).  What I take issue with is that "$t$" is literally meaningless (it is a bound variable in the integral).